# issue in working with life cycle of input method service in android

Tags: android

I'm confused of understanding the `Life cycle` of `InputMethodService` since I have no idea about how to `DEBUG` that like `Activity Life cycle` , I have read [this post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/search/label/Input%20methods), but now I want to know that when we call the `closing()` of `KeyboardView`, then our keyboard is closed, but when the keyboard is re shown or opened the what method is called there??